# Interpreting OPL's solution files

Tags: cplex, opl

I am running opl from the command line and I am saving each integer solution found so far with:

```
execute {     
  cplex.intsolfileprefix="sofar";
}
```

However, the resultant is written as XML.  Is there a conversion routine in existence so that I can access the variables' values?  Ideally, I would like to have executed the "execute DISPLAY {...}" code but that might be asking too much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the setting "Postprocess feasible solutions"?

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplide/topics/opl_ide_script_cover_post.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't seem to help.  I'm old school -- command-line interface, oplrun is my mode of interaction -- so it took me a while to run my model in the IDE but even when I found the settings panel and specified 'Display feasible solutions' it made no difference to the format solutions were saved in.

Comment: Hi, that s because indeed you did not use the IDE. To do the same in scripting, you can write  execute { thisOplModel.settings.run_processFeasible=true; };

Comment: Ah!  This did it and I now can avoid that new-fangled IDE thingy ;-)  Marking solved.